# Upgrading ASP.Net Webform from 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7

I've been spending the past few hours trying to get a 2.0 .Net ASP.Net app working with 4.0. I've struggled through different web.config hurdles, but now I'm stuck at something weird.

When trying to access the site, it only renders up to the form tag. The source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="App_Themes/Default/Menu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>
            Webpage
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form
```

Then it just ends. I can't find anything related in any logs.

The code in the master page where this html is from should continue like this:

```
 id="form1" runat="server">
```

To complete the form tag.

Any ideas?

Edit: Found a global try catch that would eat up any errors from the web application.

Comment: What code is there in your asp.net file just after that point?

Comment: Can you confirm the aspx page/master page have complete html in them. Also, do you get any errors if you rebuild the app? The update may have tripped over something.

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: @DanielCasserly, Added to the main post, it's the continuation of the form tag with ID and Runat attribute.

Comment: @ChrisFelstead, I can confirm that, the website runs on my development server as we speak. I forgot however to mention that I'm precompiling it with aspnet_compiler.exe before sending it to the server, as with the version before this.

Comment: @Xaisoft, it happens regardless of browser, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your content is truncated like that, it means that you have gotten an unhandled runtime exception.  Check your application event logs for errors or warnings (found under Windows Logs -> Application in Event Viewer, for Windows 7 at least).

If there is no error/warning logged there, perhaps something in your code is getting the exception and swallowing it.  Check your exception handlers to see if the code there is getting reached.

Comment: Not getting any errors in the log though. Am I looking in the wrong place? Using the Event Viewer.

Comment: I should have specified errors or warnings; ASP.NET runtime errors are usually logged at the warning level.

Comment: I'm checking Custom Views -> Administrative Events. I assume this custom view would pick up both warnings and errors. Still, nothing.

Comment: Will typically be under Windows Logs -> Application.

Comment: Can't find anything related there, just information events regarding other things.

Comment: My guess is that you may be handling or swallowing some exceptions somewhere, then.  The application event log will only show unhandled exceptions.  I'd try setting some breakpoints in your `catch` blocks.

Comment: You have no idea how much hair I still have left thanks to you. I ventured into the code base and found a well hidden, almost global try catch.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your DOCTYPE to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd”>
```

Comment: Please give reason for downvote.  I did not say this would work, it was merely a suggestion from what I read here:  http://www.howtoasp.net/asp-net-4-0-tutorials/how-to-set-xhtml-1-1-doctype-in-asp-net-4-0/